# Why must charts on a manifold necessarily overlap?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

My (physics) lecture notes for differentiable manifolds say that the charts will *necessarily* overlap and therefore we need smooth transitions functions. Is this strictly true, can't we always define charts such that they don't overlap?

Comment: I guess they must certainly overlap in connected manifolds.

Comment: is this because the charts are *open* sets?

Comment: As Randall said, they don't need to overlap. That being said, some texts define manifolds as being connected, in which case they do. (And yes, it is because they are open sets and the manifold is connected).

Comment: If they not, just consider the union of half of the charts and the union of the other half. You get two open sets that cover the space and that do no overlap, so the manifold isn't connected.

Comment: @AlexGower  Yes.  And, you are right, charts needs not overlap:  give $(0,1)$ the manifold structure with only one chart (itself).

Comment: @Randall Some people would argue that is an overlap, although it is based on definition. My definition of not overlapping is that there exists charts $A,B$ such that $A\cap B=\varnothing$. This definition is canonical because it is used to define connectedness.

Comment: I'm confused about the precise question being asked.  Is it:  for any two charts $A$ and $B$, we must have $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$?  Or is it:  for any chart $A$ there is a chart $B$ with $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$?  Or is it: for any chart $A$, there is a chart $B\neq A$ with $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$?

Comment: The question is whether we can have a set of charts such that *all* of them have a zero intersection

Comment: But I think I'm happy now

Comment: If you're happy now, perhaps you'd like to write up an answer to your own question?

Comment: What do you mean by "the charts" of a differentiable manifold $M$? The charts in some *given* differentiable atlas for $M$? Note that there may be many such atlases. More generally, what is the definition of a  differentiable manifold?

Answer (score -1):

Since the charts are defined to be *open*, this means that, if we are to cover the entire manifold, we will necessarily have to have charts with a non-zero intersection.

Comment: This is false. There are manifolds that can be covered by one chart.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I intuitively believe that some manifolds can be covered by one chart, in that case would you just not need the transition funcitons? Would it still be a differentiable manifold?